# Скрыть информацию при пустом поле в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Есть код:

```
prin<<<HERE
<table border="0" width="250px" style=" position:absolute; top:140px; left:350px; display: inline-block; white-space:normal;">
<tr>

<td>

<p style=" font-size:25px; padding-left: px;">$myrowd[name]</p>
<hr>
<h style=" padding-top:10px; padding-left: px;">$reg</h><br>
<hr>
<h style=" padding-top:10px; padding-left: px;">$myrowd[textar]</h><br>
<hr>
<h style=" padding-top:10px; padding-left: px;">$myrowd[textaus]</h><br>
<hr>
<p style=" padding-top:10px; padding-left: px;">$myrowd[number]</p>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
HERE;
```

О пользователе выводятся данные в переменных. Мне нужно сделать следующее: если поле (к примеру, `textar`) в базе пустое, то вот это:

```
 <h style=" padding-top:10px; padding-left: px;">$myrowd[textar]</h><br>
        <hr>
```

не отображается. Как это осуществить? Я предполагаю, что можно с помощью if, но я не знаю, как в переменную вложить кусок кода, да наверняка это будет некрасиво.

Comment: Уточните как-нибудь последнюю часть вопроса, а то я уже пятый раз перечитываю, но преобразовать всё в какую-то логическую цепочку не могу. Может старею, но ... ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может так подойдет:

```
<?php
    if(isset($myrowd[textar] && $myrowd[textar] == null || $myrowd[textar] == "")){
        $string_textar = '<h style=" padding-top:10px; padding-left: px;">$myrowd[textar]</h><br>/n<hr>';
    } else {
        $string_textar = '<h style=" padding-top:10px; padding-left: px;">$myrowd[textar]</h><br>';
        }
    print<<<HERE
    <table border="0" width="250px" style=" position:absolute; top:140px; left:350px; display: inline-block; white-space:normal;">
    <tr>

    <td>

    <p style=" font-size:25px; padding-left: px;">$myrowd[name]</p>
    <hr>
    <h style=" padding-top:10px; padding-left: px;">$regreg</h><br>
    <hr>
    $string_textar
    <hr>
    <h style=" padding-top:10px; padding-left: px;">$myrowd[textaus]</h><br>
    <hr>
    <p style=" padding-top:10px; padding-left: px;">$myrowd[number]</p>

    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    HERE;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Что-то типа этого:

```
$string="<table border='0' width='250px' style=' position:absolute; top:140px; left:350px; display: inline-block; white-space:normal;'><tr><td>";
foreach($myrowd as $key => $value){
   if($value!=""){
    $string.="<h style=' padding-top:10px; padding-left: px;'>$value</h><br><hr>";
   }
 }
$string.="</td></tr></table>";
echo $string;
```

Обходим массив, проверяем его на существование переменных.
Если переменная есть то формируем HTML-код и заносим в строку.
Потом выводим строку в браузер.

Comment: Ну проверишь ты на существование, есть все переменные, выведет всё! Ибо из БД тащится все, и пустая переменная тоже переменная!

Comment: Согласен. Тупанул. Поправил.